# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mongodb, next.js

I am making a multiselect component in Next.js and I am using states and setting states. However, this error occurs:

[image]

whenever I click this:

[image]

This is the code of MultiSelect.tsx:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

import {
  Command,
  CommandDialog,
  CommandEmpty,
  CommandGroup,
  CommandInput,
  CommandItem,
  CommandList,
  CommandSeparator,
  CommandShortcut,
} from "@/components/ui/command";

interface MultiSelectProps {
  placeholder: string
  collections: CollectionType[]
  value: string[]
  onChange: (value: string) => void
  onRemove: (value: string) => void
}

const MultiSelect: React.FC<MultiSelectProps> = ({
  placeholder,
  collections,
  value,
  onChange,
  onRemove,
}) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Command className="overflow-visible bg-white">
      <CommandInput
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={inputValue}
        onValueChange={setInputValue}
        onBlur={() => setOpen(false)}
        onFocus={() => setOpen(true)}
      />
      <div className="relative mt-2">
        {open && (
          <CommandGroup className="absolute w-full z-10 top-0 overflow-auto border rounded-md shadow-md">
            {collections.map((collection) => (
              <CommandItem key={collection._id}>{collection.title}</CommandItem>
            ))}
          </CommandGroup>
        )}
      </div>
    </Command>
  );
};

export default MultiSelect;
```

and here is the code from the ProductForm.tsx:

```js
"use client";

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Separator } from "../ui/separator";
import { z } from "zod";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Textarea } from "../ui/textarea";
import ImageUpload from "../custom ui/ImageUpload";
import { useParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import Delete from "../custom ui/Delete";
import MultiText from "../custom ui/MultiText";
import MultiSelect from "../custom ui/MultiSelect";

const formSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().min(2).max(20),
  description: z.string().min(2).max(500).trim(),
  media: z.array(z.string()),
  category: z.string(),
  collections: z.array(z.string()),
  tags: z.array(z.string()),
  size: z.array(z.string()),
  colors: z.array(z.string()),
  price: z.coerce.number().min(0.1),
  expense: z.coerce.number().min(0.1),
});

interface ProductFormProps {
  initialData?: ProductType | null; // Must have ? to make it optional
}

const ProductForm: React.FC<ProductFormProps> = ({ initialData }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  //const params = useParams();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [collections, setCollections] = useState<CollectionType[]>([]);

  const getCollections = async () => {
    try{
      setLoading(true)
      const res = await fetch("/api/collections", {
        method: "GET",
      })
      const data = await res.json()
      setCollections(data)
      setLoading(false)
    }catch(err) {
      console.log("[collections_GET]", err)
      toast.error("Something went wrong. Please try again.")
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getCollections()
  }, [])

  // 1. Define your form.
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: initialData
      ? initialData
      : {
          title: "",
          description: "",
          media: [],
          category: "",
          collections: [],
          tags: [],
          sizes: [],
          colors: [],
          price: 0.1,
          expense: 0.1,
        },
  });

  const handleKeyPress = (
    e:
      | React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>
      | React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  // 2. Define a submit handler.
  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    // Do something with the form values.
    // ✅ This will be type-safe and validated.
    //console.log(values)
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const url = initialData
        ? `/api/products/${initialData._id}`
        : "/api/products";
      const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(values),
      });
      if (res.ok) {
        setLoading(false);
        toast.success(`Product ${initialData ? "updated" : "created"}.`);
        window.location.href = "/products";
        router.push("/products");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("[products_POST]", err);
      toast.error("Something went wrong. Please try again.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="p-10">
      {initialData ? (
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
          <p className="text-heading2-bold">Edit Product</p>
          <Delete id={initialData._id} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p className="text-heading2-bold">Create Product</p>
      )}
      <Separator className="bg-grey-1 my-4 mb-7" />
      <Form {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="title"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    placeholder="Title"
                    {...field}
                    onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>The title of the product.</FormDescription>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="description"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Description</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Textarea
                    placeholder="Description"
                    {...field}
                    rows={5}
                    onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>
                  The description of the product.
                </FormDescription>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="media"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Image</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <ImageUpload
                    value={field.value}
                    onChange={(url) => field.onChange([...field.value, url])}
                    onRemove={(url) =>
                      field.onChange([
                        ...field.value.filter((image) => image !== url),
                      ])
                    }
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>The image of the product.</FormDescription>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <div className="md: grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-8">
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="price"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Price ($)</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      type="number"
                      placeholder="Price"
                      {...field}
                      onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>The price of the product.</FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="expense"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Expense ($)</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      type="number"
                      placeholder="Expense"
                      {...field}
                      onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>The expense of the product.</FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="category"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Category</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      placeholder="Category"
                      {...field}
                      onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage className="text-red-1" />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="tags"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Tags</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <MultiText
                      placeholder="Tags"
                      value={field.value}
                      onChange={(tag) => field.onChange([...field.value, tag])}
                      onRemove={(tagToRemove) =>
                        field.onChange([
                          ...field.value.filter((tag) => tag !== tagToRemove),
                        ])
                      }
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage className="text-red-1" />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="collections"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Collections</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <MultiSelect
                      placeholder="Collections"
                      collections={collections}
                      value={field.value}
                      onChange={(_id) => field.onChange([...field.value, _id])}
                      onRemove={(idToRemove) =>
                        field.onChange([
                          ...field.value.filter((collectionId) => collectionId !== idToRemove),
                        ])
                      }
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage className="text-red-1" />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex gap-10">
            <Button type="submit" className="bg-blue-1 text-white">
              Submit
            </Button>
            <Button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => router.push("/collections")}
              className="bg-blue-1 text-white"
            >
              Discard
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductForm;
```

When I click the multiselect component, I am expecting it to show the current collection list.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by downgrading the version of "cmdk" with the command:

```
npm install cmdk@0.2.1
```